# How to stop Gnome dock reappearing when a window is full screen?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, ubuntu-dock

I have my dock set to auto-hide, but when a window is full screen with a game it reappears briefly whenever I move the mouse towards that side of the screen, even when the mouse is captured by the window. How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be changed in the settings app or `gnome-tweaks`, but setting `/org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/autohide-in-full-screen` to false in `dconf-editor` will prevent the dock from reappearing over any app running in full screen mode.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Worked for me but I had to set the setting to `true` and then back to `false` in order to make it work ...

Comment: I was looking for the exact opposite - I wanted to be able to reveal the Dock when an app was in fullscreen and setting the `autohide-in-full-screen` to true solved it.